# Where can I find White Whales?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

In Assassin's Creed 4 offline, where can I find White Whales? I need the money from the skin to upgrade the Jackdaw to elite.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not online, then you more than likely won't be able to find any White Whales on your map. White Whales are only found through online Community Events.

> The White Whale is available with an online connection only during Community Events -- what this means is that the White Whale will show up in your game only if you are online.

Source: http://www.ign.com/wikis/assassins-creed-4-black-flag/White_Whale

Answer (score 1):

White Whales only show up in the game when you're online and connected to the Ubisoft network.  [Here's a link to the source of this info.](http://www.ign.com/wikis/assassins-creed-4-black-flag/White_Whale)